# Add plus 1 to localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add +1 on every page reload at localStorage, but it doesn't work:

```
var Counter = localStorage.getItem('Counter');

localStorage.setItem('Counter', Counter + 1);

var CounterStorage = console.log(localStorage.getItem('Counter'));
```

My results on page reload:

1. 1
2. 11
3. 111

But what I need is:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: `localStorage` only holds strings. To perform mathematical addition you need to convert the value to an int or float - `var Counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('Counter') || 0, 10);`

Comment: Ah, ok, good to know - thx!